# Run a batch script in another directory than the batch script directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that I run from the Windows Task Scheduler, the advantage is that the scheduler has the option of "Start in:", this allows me to run the batch script in a totally separate directory.

In the cmd prompt the equivalent would be to open a cmd prompt window in Directory1 and type out the full Directory2/batchscript.bat.

However, I was wondering if there was a way inside my batchscript.bat to set the directory to "run" in?

Comment: That's quite trivial and easy to find if you only would look for :-( `CD` or better `CD /D` or `pushd/popd` See help at the cmd line with `cd /?` or  `pushd /?`

Comment: Yes, I looked around and those were the answers i've seen. I posted on here in the interest of time until I can sit down and do a proper course (Udemy) on this stuff. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Regardless you still need to type in the path to the batch file.  Whether you do it by changing the directory or just executing it with the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
set "your_dir=path_to_your_directory"     
pushd %cd%
cd %your_dir%
run_your_command
popd
```

Comment: If you want to run another batch-file, and then continue with the first one, you need to use `call run_your_command`.  (Otherwise, operation will terminate before getting to `popd`)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. It looked like what I saw when googling around as well but this was straightforward and useful :)